# OpenGL ES 2.0 Texture Mapping to Fill Quad on Raspberry Pi

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to setup my Vertices and Texture Coordinates such that I have a single Quad ( 2 triangles ) covering the entire OpenGL Window. I want to then update the texture as I receive images from my camera.

It is working except for that my streaming texture never fills the entire screen and the texture pixels are repeated outside of the intended texture ( see images below ).

How do I setup my vertices and texture coordinates so that my texture will fill the quad without repeating?

Here is how I generate my texture:

```
    glGenTextures(1, &m_dataFrame);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_dataFrame);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame.bits());
    // CUSTOM
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Initial Attempts:

```
// Setup the vertices and texture coordinates
float scaler = 1.0f;
static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
    -(1.0f/scaler), -(1.0f/scaler), 0.0f, // First triangle bottom left
    (1.0f/scaler), -(1.0f/scaler), 0.0f,
    -(1.0f/scaler),  (1.0f/scaler), 0.0f,
    (1.0f/scaler),  -(1.0f/scaler), 0.0f, // Second triangle bottom right
    (1.0f/scaler),  (1.0f/scaler), 0.0f,
    -(1.0f/scaler),  (1.0f/scaler), 0.0f,
};
static const GLfloat textureVertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,
};
```

This results in the following image:
[image]

```
// Setup the vertices and texture coordinates
float x = 1.0f;
float y = 1.0f;
static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
    -(x*2), -(y*2), 0.0f, // First triangle bottom left
    (x*2), -(y*2), 0.0f,
    -(x*2),  (y*2), 0.0f,
    (x*2),  -(y*2), 0.0f, // Second triangle bottom right
    (x*2),  (y*2), 0.0f,
    -(x*2),  (y*2), 0.0f,
};
static const GLfloat textureVertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,
};
```

This results in the following image:
[image]

Comment: Chances are that the setup of your texture coordinates is broken. But you're not showing the code where that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I've used for rendering a textured quad on the Raspberry Pi (in Swift, but the syntax is similar to what you'd use for C). Setting up the texture parameters:

```
    glEnable(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D))
    glGenTextures(1, &cameraOutputTexture)
    glActiveTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE0));
    glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), cameraOutputTexture)
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER), GL_NEAREST)
```

uploading the texture:

```
    glActiveTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE0))
    glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), cameraOutputTexture)
    glTexImage2D(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), 0, GL_RGB, 1280, 720, 0, GLenum(GL_RGB), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), buffers[Int(currentBuffer)].start)
```

and rendering it:

```
glClear(GLenum(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
shader.use()

let squareVertices:[GLfloat] = [
    -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  1.0,
]

let textureCoordinates:[GLfloat] = [
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
]

glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), 0, 0, squareVertices)
glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordinateAttribute, 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), 0, 0, textureCoordinates)

glUniform1i(GLint(textureCoordinateAttribute), 1)

glDrawArrays(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP), 0, 4)
eglSwapBuffers(display, surface)
```

I might be rotating the image to account for rotation in the camera that I'm using as an input source, so you may need to tweak the vertices or coordinates if you see your image rendering upside-down.